# Solr7.2- Not able to upload csv file with fields containing Numbers as well as Alphanumeric Values

Tags: solr

I am a newbie in Solr.
Trying to upload a csv file to Solr in my local.
Here is the CSV File

```
Col_1   Name  Workouts  To_Do
1       Abh     gym      123
2       Kar    pilate   wh123Ap
3       adi     “sw     Like123
```

Command : curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/demo4/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/home/User1/solr-7.2.1/example/test_solr_csv/test1.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv;charset=utf-8'

Value in managedschema:

```
<field name="Col_1" type="plongs"/>
<field name="Name" type="text_general"/>
<field name="To_Do" type="string"/>
<field name="Workouts" type="text_general"/>
```

I guess the problem is due to the mixed datatype of the fields. I had already set the type of To_Do field to "string". But after running the command it got changed back to "plongs" And
I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":231},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=1c5909cc-8d10-40d7-96fb-f3b25aa2d965] Error adding field 'To_Do'='wh123Ap' msg=For input string: \"wh123Ap\"",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: Did you change the managed-schema file manually without reloading the core/collection? Was the index empty when you did? Did you start with the schemaless-mode (`data_driven_config` iirc)?

Comment: 1) bin/solr start
2) bin/solr create -c demo4
3) Then I changed the values in managed-schema file. After that I ran the curl command.

Comment: I just made the changes in the managed schema file. Can you please elaborate on what other changes i have to make.

Comment: Solr doesn't reload the managed-schema file automagically. Stop Solr, change the file, then start Solr again - or if you only have a single node, reload the core/collection in the Admin interface. Or use the SchemaAPI if you're running multiple nodes in a cluster.